# Is there any significant difference in meaning between 便利な安い物 and 便利で安い物?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Is there any significant difference in meaning between 便利な安い物 and 便利で安い物?

- 便利な安い物: handy cheap thing
- 便利で安い物: handy, cheap thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is certainly a difference between the two, but whether it could be called "significant" or not would be up to each individual.

> 「便利{べんり}**な**安{やす}い物{もの}」

「便利**な**」 is in the 連体形{れんたいけい}(attributive form); therefore, the native ears would instinctively expect a ***noun*** to follow.

「安い物」, even though it is technically in the "adjective + noun" form, would feel more like one word (noun) here.  Since there happens to exist the word (noun) 「安物{やすもの} = "cheap item"」, that is what 「安い物」 almost sounds and feels like in the phrase 「便利**な**安い物」.

> 「便利**で**安い物」

「便利**で**」 is in the 連用形｛れんようけい}(continuative form); therefore, the native ears would naturally expect a ***verb*** or ***another adjective*** to follow.

What follows?  The adjective 「安い」 does, making the phrase flow stress-free.  Two adjectives modifying a noun; No problem.

So, "one adjective vs. two adjectives" is the difference in the practical sense, if not in a technical sense.