# な with a な-adjective before another adjective

Tags: grammar, adjectives

> 赤ちゃんも安全**な**温かい場所で大きく強くなる。

This sentence is from a book for young children.

Why aren't the two adjectives connected with で　（安全で温かい場所）?

I'm not sure if it's important, but in the book the sentence is written with hiragana only.

Comment: Related: [Is there any significant difference in meaning between 便利な安い物 and 便利で安い物?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26188/43676), [i-adjective + na-adjective + noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30754/43676)

Comment: @aguijonazo thank you! So, can 温かい場所 be perceived as one word and considered to be one?